# When div resize in JavaScript call function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am learnig JavaScript and I notice that I don't know how to trigger change in my test web site when div resize.

Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var  expanded = document.getElementById('Proba').style.width='100%';
function Expand() {
document.getElementById('Proba').style.width='100%';
document.getElementById('Proba').style.height='100%'
document.getElementById('Proba').style.position='absolute';
document.getElementById('Proba').style.left='0px';
document.getElementById('Proba').style.top='0px';
document.getElementById('Proba').style.opacity='0.68';
document.getElementById('Proba').style.zIndex='1';
}
</script>
<style>
#Proba
{
background-color:#b0c4de;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body id="Body">

<script>
if (expanded=true) {
document.write('You did it!')}
</script>
<div id="Proba" onclick="Expand()"><div>

</body>
</html>
```

Obviously, if statement doesn't give me what I want.

Comment: try if (expanded) {...} Your if does not have a valid evaluation condition.

Comment: @peshkira The question is about running the code when the div's size changes. An if-clause in the global scope is going to run once when the script loads, not when there's a change in the DOM.

Comment: true... I provided a jsfiddle. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 2):

There is no onResize event for DIVs but that doesn't mean you can make your own.

http://jsfiddle.net/pJ8yH/

```
(function() {
    var resizeObjects = [];
    window.setInterval(function() {
        for(var i=0; i<resizeObjects.length; i++) {
            var ro = resizeObjects[i];
            if(ro.element.parentNode == null) {
                // node is not part of the DOM right now
                continue;
            } else if(ro.element.offsetHeight != ro.height || ro.element.offsetWidth != ro.width) {
                ro.height = ro.element.offsetHeight;
                ro.width = ro.element.offsetWidth;
                for(var j=0; j<ro.callbacks.length; j++) {
                    ro.callbacks[j].apply(ro.element);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 100);
    HTMLElement.prototype.resize = function(callback) {
        if(arguments.length == 1 && typeof(callback) == "function") {
            // add a new callback function
            var obj = null;
            for(var i=0; i<resizeObjects.length; i++) {
                if(resizeObjects[i].element == this) {
                    obj = resizeObjects[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(obj) {
                obj.callbacks.push(callback);
            } else {
                resizeObjects.push({
                    "element": this,
                    "callbacks": [callback],
                    "height": this.offsetHeight,
                    "width": this.offsetWidth
                });
            }
        } else if(arguments.length == 0) {
            // trigger resize callback functions
            for(var i=0; i<resizeObjects.length; i++) {
                var ro = resizeObjects[i];
                if(ro.element == this) {
                    for(var j=0; j<ro.callbacks.length; j++) {
                        ro.callbacks[j].apply(this);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Test it out

```
var counter=0;
document.getElementById("demo1").resize(function() {
    this.innerHTML = (++counter);
});
document.getElementById("demo2").resize(function() {
    this.innerHTML = (++counter);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really making my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to create your own expanded event.  Here's some code below that creates an `expanded` event for your object.  You can create your own event framework using this code, or just use jQuery.

At the top of the code a create the event, which is reused when the event is fired.  At the end of the `expand()` function, I call `fireEvent()`.  `fireEvent()` will trigger the callbacks added in `subscribe()`.

A few notes:

- It was a waste to call `getElementById()` for each line in `expand()`. Better to just assign the value to variable.
- I'm pretty sure IE 9+ uses `dispatchEvent()`, and `addEventListener()`, so you don't need the conditional statements unless you plan to support IE8.  `createEvent()` is not in IE.

### Code

```
var exapndEvent = createEvent('expanded');

function expand() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('Proba');

    elem.style.width = '100%';
    elem.style.height = '100%'
    elem.style.position = 'absolute';
    elem.style.left = '0px';
    elem.style.top = '0px';
    elem.style.opacity = '0.68';
    elem.style.zIndex = '1';

    fireEvent(elem, exapndEvent);
}

function createEvent(name) {
    var event;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent(name, true, true);
    } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = name;
    }

    return event;
}

function fireEvent(elem, event) {
    if (document.createEvent) {
        elem.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        elem.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
    }
}

// subscribe to elemenet event
function subscribe(elem, eventName, callback) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
        elem.attachEvent(eventName, callback);
    }
}

// subscribe to expanded event
subscribe(document.getElementById('Proba'), 'expanded', function () {
    this.innerHTML = 'You did It!';
});
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HWSGg/)

Comment: In short this is what I want, but i is to complicated for me, because I am just learning JavaScript. @peshkira: I didn't know that is sholud put == in front of 100%. I thought I just define variable.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem here is that javascript isn't inherently 'stateful' as you're using it. That if statement you added isn't re-evaluated each time you click, it's only evaluated the when the initial HTML is evaluated.

Instead, you might want to have something in your expand function that either shows the "you did it" text itself, or calls another function that does it. You could also add listeners/events to your page/script, but that's a bit more complex.

The third problem is your equality checks. `expanded=true` is an assignment, setting expanded to true every time. Your initial assignment, 
`var  expanded = ...width='100%'` is also setting that width to 100%, and I'm not sure what expanded will be set to, probably true because that statement isn't really 'falsey' or undefined because the assignment is a void action.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Auawr/

As Juhana stated there is an issue with the execution order due to the way you have written your scripts.

The check whether the div is expanded should be within the expand function or in a separate function that is called after expand. Also note that using one equal sign (=) is an assignment and not an equality check

```
...
var  expanded = document.getElementById('Proba').style.width == '100%';
if (expanded==true) {
 alert("You did it!");    
}
```

...

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what are you up to, but take a look at w3c tutorial about resize

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery's [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) function for this. In your code, this would be:

`$("#div-id").resize(function(){ alert("You did it!"); });`

Comment: Whoops, checked the window instead of the div. Sorry

Comment: The question doesn't mention jQuery anywhere.

Comment: It was a method of doing it.